# requiring packages with JS instead of the asset pipeline - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a plugin called `simplemde` I used bower to bring in the plug in. The javascript it imported is trying to require other addons but when I try to run the code I get this error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I understand the you cannot require from the client side unless you make changes to the asset pipeline. I'm trying to find out what to do in this situation with a rails app.

## JS

```
var CodeMirror = require("codemirror");
require("codemirror/addon/edit/continuelist.js");
require("./codemirror/tablist");
require("codemirror/addon/display/fullscreen.js");
require("codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown.js");
require("codemirror/addon/mode/overlay.js");
require("codemirror/addon/display/placeholder.js");
require("codemirror/addon/selection/mark-selection.js");
require("codemirror/mode/gfm/gfm.js");
require("codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js");
```

What are some ways I can get this file to work with Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you use files from the `src` directory of the `SimpleMDE` plugin. This files should be preprocessed and assembled into one on the server side before delivering to the client. You can use minified and assembled files from the `dist` directory. If you want to use source files anyway, you should tune your asset pipeline, for example like in article [Bring CommonJS to your asset pipeline](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/04/bring-commonjs-to-your-asset-pipeline/) or use other tools, like Grunt or Gulp, for assets assembling.